# Copying Excel data from one file to the other and reformatting

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, copy, runtime-error

I am trying to copy data from one excel to the other and then reformat.

This is the code I am using:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Export", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\Khawaja\Desktop\Export.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=9, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Name"", type text}, {""Surname"", type" & _
        " text}, {""Email"", type text}, {""Action"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Export;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Export]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Export"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

My source file has data in columns. Each column has a heading of Name, Surname, Email and Action. But when I run the macro, it is not able to detect the column heads.

This is the error I get:

> The column 'Name' of the table was not found

Any idea how the error can be removed?

Comment: The third argument in Listobjects.add is XlListObjectHasHeaders. To that argument, you must type XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes.

Answer (score 0):

The argument you are looking for in Listobjects.add is XlListObjectHasHeaders. To that argument, you must type XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes. You can also type xlGuess and Excel will guess if the tables has headers. In your case you have string data in both the header and data, therefore the default xlGuess is likely failing for that reason.

```
  ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Export", Formula:= _
            "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\Khawaja\Desktop\Export.csv""),[Delimiter="","", Columns=9, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Name"", type text}, {""Surname"", type" & _
            " text}, {""Email"", type text}, {""Action"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
            "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Export;Extended Properties=""""" _
            , XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
            .CommandType = xlCmdSql
            .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Export]")
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = False
            .ListObject.DisplayName = "Export"
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Comment: I had tried this as well. The error is the same. I tried to debug it and run step by step. After creating a new Worksheet, It runs through the 'With' part one time. But then it is not able to find the main colomn heading. I cant analyze if it is becasue of the source file or the destiantion file.

Comment: Are you sure that this has even to do with the headers? Maybe the import comes up empty and therefore procs the header error.

Comment: The file from which it is importing is full of data. And the 1st row that is imported is used to address the rest of the rows. For eg. (1,1) is Name and the rows following are having name of the people. I am just referring the first value as a reference to read.

Comment: Is there any other planned way of doing the same stuff